# 2D Physics engine to simulate gravity using images

Tags: javascript, image, physics-engine

I am searching for a 2D physics engine to simulate gravity using images, preferably PNG images with transparency. So the engine will know how to calculate the collision base on the opaque parts of the image. I have only found Javascript engines that works with primitive shapes and basic HTML elements, but not with images.

Comment: Isn't `<img>` a basic html element?

Comment: I think he means that transparent sections of an image shouldn't collide.

Comment: Yes. I will use PNG images with transparency

Comment: Use the HTML5 Canvas tag. It's better and faster

Comment: found this: http://lib.ivank.net/?p=demos&d=box2D, but I don't think it recognizes the empty areas of the PNG image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One think you could do is compute the convex hull of your image ([you can have a look here](http://geomalgorithms.com/a10-_hull-1.html)) and then use those hulls to compute collisions and so on (using [GJK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gilbert%E2%80%93Johnson%E2%80%93Keerthi_distance_algorithm) for example, you can find some great explanations [here](https://youtu.be/Qupqu1xe7Io) or [here](http://box2d.org/files/GDC2010/GDC2010_Catto_Erin_GJK.pdf))

As noted by micnic, I guess you can indeed use [Box2D.js](https://github.com/hrj/box2d-js) and feed a `b2PolygonShape` why the non transparent pixels of your images (or you can compute their contours and use contours as input for the `b2PolygonShape`)

Answer (score 2):

I don't know any way to do what you desire, but you can try drawing your shapes in HTML5 Canvas and use [Box2D.js](https://github.com/hrj/box2d-js) for working with shape collision.